# How to connect to sybase DB using python?

Tags: python, sybase

We are trying to use the following:

```
import Sybase 
con=Sybase.connect('DSN','USER','PASS','DB')
c=con.cursor()
c.execute('select count(*) from TABLE')
c.fetchone()
```

We don't know what DSN is (have a  database server available though).

Could anyone please help with  the suggestions or alternate solutions?
(We have the following  database credentials): database name, database server, username and password. 
What is the best way to connect using these credentials ?

Comment: DSN is likely going to be either the database server instance name, or the FQDN/IP & port.  Have you looked at the Sybase Python documentation? http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01692.1570/doc/html/car1308847098623.html